# get angular form data value in node is empty

Tags: node.js, angular

This is angular form data append part

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('userId', this.myData.userId);
formData.append('file', this.file);
formData.append('action', 'upload');
```

And I send it to node server like this.

```
return this.http.post<any>(`${Server}/uploadPhoto`, formData);
```

But I can't get req.body value in node server
I used Express.
But `req.body` is empty.

This is node get part.

```
exports.uploadPhoto = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        console.log(req.body))
        res.status(200).send(req.body)
    } catch {
        res.status(400).send()
    }
```

Return value and node get value are all `{}`.
If I don't use formdata, node server works well.
I can get other values without formdata.

I think, it is due to angular header option or node accept type option, but I'm not sure.

This is node header part

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding');
```

Answer (score 0):

For file upload with form data, you can try this library on your express API, inside have a lot of example how to implement this middleware.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer